# Unable to open file for reading on All-in-One Migration on wordpress after searching for solutions

Tags: wordpress, plugins, migration

After I searched solutions:

1. maximize upload file: https://help.servmask.com/2018/10/27/how-to-increase-maximum-upload-file-size-in-wordpress/
2. From reading this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-open-file-for-reading-5/, but not found the basic version to download this plugin: https://import.wp-migration.com/en/

How do we solve this issue?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A solution found with 4 easy steps:

1. Uninstall the All-in-One Migration
2. download the file https://import.wp-migration.com/all-in-one-wp-migration-file-extension.zip and upload this plugin
3. reinstall the All-in-One Migration
4. Import

Comment: nope this does not work for me.
the upload stuck a 0.0% ...

Comment: doesn't work with WP 6.1.1 or later

Answer (score 1):

Increase the PHP parameters. In my case the dump weighed 8Gb

Example:

```
max_execution_time = 6000
post_max_size = 10000M
upload_max_filesize = 10000M
```